# How to execute javascript within a website using asynctask in Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-asynctask, jsoup, htmlunit

Let's say the android app has to read the score of my badgets in stackoverflow. See animated picture below.
[image]

Is there any known implementation to solve the problem?
Something like:

```
/**
 * get badget score by bagdet name
 * @param name the badget name
 */
public String getBadgetByName(String name){
    if(userProfileURL != null){
        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(userProfileURL)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Document doc = response.parse();
            // TODO: get badget by name async
            String result = ...
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the main issue is to find a solution for evaluating javascript within any HTML parser, in order to get results.

**Update 1:**

Why no Webview? 
In some cases I need to handle jobs in background. Let's say the app need to read the score every 10 minutes without having to open the app all the time.

Comment: You need to use the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) for this

Comment: I see the API does not help because I cannot get the score using the API

Comment: And why is a webview not an option?Just use it to render the html and then parse with jsoup.

Comment: well it's a legitimate question. In some cases it's useful to get the score in background. So I want to handle jobs in the background. A webview can only be used if the app is in foreground, right?